# c# mongo driver installation

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I try to install MongoDB C# official driver with Package Manager console in VS2013. It has some dependencies, and they should be installed by commands like this:

```
Install-Package MongoDB.Bson
```

But I have got such error for each package:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'MongoDB.Bson 2.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compa
>   tible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  MongoDB.Bson
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: If I'm reading the [nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Bson/) correctly you must target .NET 4.5, but your error indicates you are targeting .NET 4.0. You can change the target in the project properties in visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

> '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client',

This is .NET 4.0 Client Profile, which Mongo driver doesn't support.

Maybe you didn't intended to use [.NET 4.0 Client Profile.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912(v=vs.110).aspx) Go to your project properties and switch to .NET 4.5 (because it's the minimum framework version supported by the whole [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Bson/)).

Comment: Thank you, problem can also be solved by adding direct referenses to project

Comment: @Kelnmyir You went the wrong way with your approach, because Mongo driver might use some classes or facilities from newer framework versions. Since .NET 4.x uses CLR 4.0, you can still add them to your project, but if Mongo has defined that you need 4.5 or newer it's because they rely on something that's not present on .NET 4.